# Installed texlive 2020 but still cannot install latexmk due to the 2019 local TeX Live

Tags: texlive, latexmk, update

Summary: I cannot install/update latexmk because it says the local tex live (2019) is older than remote (2020), but in fact I already installed texlive 2020 from the official [source](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html).

Notes: The latexmk file exist in my `/Library/Tex/texbin/`.

---

Terminal:

Type `sudo tlmgr install latexmk`, get

```
sudo tlmgr install latexmk
sh: line 1: 35636 Abort trap: 6           wget --version > /dev/null 2>&1

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

But my latex version is 2020: type `latex --version`, get

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Copyright 2020 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.02
```

Comment: You need to set the PATH so `sudo tlmgr` uses the 2020 one not the 2019 one.

Comment: How did you install TeX Live 2020?

Comment: PS: you shouldn’t have to install latexmk in TeX Live.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I installed via MacTex.pkg, got from the link in the answer. I don't know how to update via terminal b/c I cannot find the manual to walkaround the old version

Comment: Where is your tlmgr located? Run `which tlmgr`.

Comment: You don't need to "walk around" the old version; /Library/TeX/texbin should point to the 2020 binaries and your run of `latex --version` shows that it does. Try `sudo /Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr update latexmk` to make sure the path is right. Note: I use `update` NOT `install` since latexmk is part of the TeX Live 2020 distribution. I also don't remember if latexmk has been updated since the release of TeX Live 2020.

Comment: @HerbSchulz it just don't work. (1) Run `which tlmgr`, should `/usr/local/bin/tlmgr` (2) Run `/usr/local/bin/tlmgr
sudo /Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr update latexmk`, show `tlmgr itself needs to be updated.` /n `Please do this via either` /n `tlmgr update --self` (partical) (3) Run `tlmgr update --self`, show `Error [...] tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).` . It's just an endless loop.

Comment: @HerbSchulz sorry for typo, the (2) should be "Run `sudo /Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr update latexmk`"

Comment: Did you install any other TeX Distribution since you report that you have a tlmgr in /usr/local/bin? MacTeX didn’t install that!

Comment: You need to prepend /Library/TeX/texbin to your PATH variable. How you do this depends upon which shell you are using. If you are using the bash shell add the line `export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:${PATH}` to your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile, which ever you already have.

Comment: @HerbSchulz thanks. I already installed it by removing all tex distributions and reinstall only 2020. It works :)